# How to get group info of a user

Tags: xmpp, xmppframework

**I get a user's JID,i want to get the group info that the user has joined by user JID. 
Can someone help me ?Please.**

Comment: which client library and server you are using?

Comment: I am using XMPPFramework on iOS

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which storage type you are using in there (CoreData/Memory) - the 'groups' field on the user (XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject) is a 1:m relation to the groups (XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject) of that user, and each group also has a 1:m relation to users (group.users).

So you should be able to get the user object via the jid of that user ([xmppRosterStorage userForJID:jid ...]), and from there, get the groups (user.groups).